# Toast not generating text from selected item from list

Tags: android, listview, adapter, toast

I've made a simple app in android with list View,In that i want to make a toast when select an item,i have tried as below but its not working..

my code is as below:

**main.java**

```
    package com.example.listview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {


    String items[]={"Car","Bird","Bike","Flower"};
    String category[]={"Sports","Birds","Sports","Nature"};
    int icons[]={R.drawable.car,R.drawable.bird,R.drawable.bike,R.drawable.flower};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
        List <HashMap<String,String>> aList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            HashMap<String,String> hm=new HashMap<String, String>();
            hm.put("txt","Item : "+items[i]);
            hm.put("category","Category : "+category[i]);
            hm.put("icon",Integer.toString(icons[i]));
            aList.add(hm);
        }
        String []from={"icon","txt","category"};
        int []to={R.id.image,R.id.text,R.id.category};
        SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(),aList,R.layout.list,from,to);
        final ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String selectedValue =(String) (lv.getItemAtPosition(position));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),selectedValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    });
    }


}
```

please help me..thanx in advance

Comment: Nothing was coming because `selectedValue` was returning null.

Comment: so what should i do for getting textvalue from list "items"?

Comment: try adding Log inside onItemClick for selectedValue and let us know what are you getting.

Comment: @jigar its working! check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17038618/539472

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HashMap<String, String> selectedValue = (HashMap<String, String>) (lv.getItemAtPosition(position));         
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(selectedValue.keySet());             
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedValue.get("txt"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

That hashmap has got keys which are present in that `list`. That list is actually the `from` array which you have given. Just give the corresponding key to display the corresponding text.

Its working. :)

Comment: @sunil When I tried `lv.getItemAtPosition(position).getClass()` it was returning that the object is of type `java.util.HashMap`. From there on I tried fetching the key values and it turned out to be `from[]` array.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this way get selected item

```
      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                            long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Position is: "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       String selectedFromList = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),selectedFromList , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            });
```

Comment: did you see the list item in list view?

Comment: yep...the ListView is completely generated with items ,thats not problem...but problem is when i click on any of item from a list toast shouls be generated showing category and itemname of that ute,but its not working.

Comment: try this edit if this is not working then try to print position direct

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String selectedValue = from[position];
```

Comment: toast generating "icon" ,"txt", "category"...i need its values...bro...!

Answer (score 0):

You can take the adapter and take value from it.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
            String selectedValue =(String) (lv.getAdapter().getItem(position));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am so confused on what you are doing, why don't you just do it like this:

```
String selectedValue = items[position];
```

instead of:

```
String selectedValue =(String) (lv.getItemAtPosition(position));
```