# show toast or progressbar on alertDialog item selected

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, toast

I have an alertDialog with a few items.
When an Item is selected, there are some Web services calls 
and only when they are done the dialog closes. 
I would like to let the user know he/she shold wait.

I've tried using progress bar and Toast.
In the Toast version, if I just show the Toast,
it does show - but only after the dialog was closed.

I also tried running the Toast on another thread, which caused the application to crash.

Here is some example of the code:

```
private void chooseFromClosestSamplePoints(final ArrayList<Place> places) {     
        if (null != places) {
            final String[] items = new String[places.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < places.size(); i++) {
                Place place = places.get(i);
                String displayText = place.mfactoryName + "," + place.msamplePointName;
                items[i] = displayText;
            }


                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            Main.this);
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.select_sample_point);
                    builder.setItems(items,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {    
                                    Place place = places.get(which);                                    
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "אנא המתן", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.show();
                                    boolean res = selectPlace(place); //this is the long running WS call
                                    if(!res)
                                    {
                                      mStartButton.setEnabled(false);
                                      showAlert("שגיאה","אנא הגדר מחדש עיר מפעל ונקודת דיגום", false);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    builder.show();
                }           
    }
```

**Edit:**
Inside the SelectPlace method , there is some code run on the UI thread itself like so:

```
private boolean selectPlace(Place place){
GetFactories factoryMethod = new GetFactories(mApp, selectedCity);
        factoryMethod.call(); //This calls the WS and awaits results

        final ArrayList<Factory> factories =factoryMethod.getFactories();
        Factory selectedFactory = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < factories.size(); i++)
        {
///Some logic
}

//Some more logic...
}
```

Would appreciate any help. 
thanks,

Omer

Comment: @Segi , this is the full code for the dialogBuilder and item selection logic. I could add the code called within selectPlace() method , but I doubt anyone will read such long piece of code. could you please explain why is it relveant , so that I will try and supply only the relveant pieces of code? thanks

Comment: i need your web service call code. i mean ui thread or asynctask part..

Comment: Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038157/toast-not-generating-text-from-selected-item-from-list/17038265?noredirect=1#comment24631048_17038265

Comment: have you got response from selectPlace method.??

Comment: @sunil - I don't see how this link is relevant?

Comment: what is showalert here.??

Comment: @Segi, this is a message showed to the user if the WS call fails. it is working and not relevant to my problem

Comment: then what is your error.??

Comment: @Segi , as I said , the Toast telling the user to wait appers only after he is done watiting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to move your web service call code into an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) class, so the UI thread is not blocked while waiting for the web service to get a response back.

Looking at your code, `factoryMethod.call();` is probably blocking the UI thread.

Comment: I'm sure it does block. that is why I'm calling the Toast before the the calls to the WS. I guess the UI thread does not show it immeditatly.

Comment: Yes, calling before doesn't guarantee the Toast will show in time before UI thread gets blocked by your WS call.